# python list comprehensions - ['False'] not printed

Tags: python

Does anyone have a clue why I can't print `False` from here:

```
print [e.text if "Born" in r.text() else 'False' for e in r.nextAll("td span .bday")]
```

or here

```
print ['False' if "Born" not in r.text() else e.text for e in r.nextAll("td span .bday")]
```

Everything works ok, except instead of `['False']` I'm getting empty brackets `[]`.

Comment: Please define `r` variable.

Comment: what's `r` variable holding?

Comment: Can you show an example html and for what exactly are you trying to print `False` ?

Comment: If you get an empty `list`, it means that `r.nextAll("td span .bday")` is an empty sequence or collection.

Comment: it comes from lambda: r, but it represents a list of <tr><td> tags. the strange thing is that expression prints the e.text when it finds it, but empty brackets instead of [False] when there is no e.text == "Born".

Comment: No the empty brackets come when there are no `td span .bday` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting empty brackets because `r.nextAll()` is returning an empty iterator.  Break it down to something simple.  For example:

```
>>> print ['foo' if False else 'bar' for e in []]
[]
>>> print ['foo' if False else 'bar' for e in [2]]
['bar']
>>> print ['foo' if False else 'bar' for e in [2, 3]]
['bar', 'bar']
>>> print ['foo' if not False else 'bar' for e in []]
[]
>>> print ['foo' if not False else 'bar' for e in [2]]
['foo']
>>> print ['foo' if not False else 'bar' for e in [2, 3]]
['foo', 'foo']
>
```

If you don't believe this, just try printing `list(r.nextAll("td span .bday"))`

Answer (score 0):

Yeap! The problem was in `list(r.nextAll("td span .bday"))` that returns empty `[]`.

I solved the problem like this:

```
lambda r: [e.text for e in r.nextAll("td span .bday")] or ['False']
```

Thanks!